# Swift Error Code: Instance member 'getStory' cannot be used on type 'StoryBrain'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: swift, xcode

Can't figure out how to go about this swift error code... Do I need to make an instance or make it static??

```
struct Story{
var storyTitle : String
var choice1 : String
var choice2 : String

init(t: String,c1: String, c2: String ) {
    storyTitle = t
    choice1 = c1
    choice2 = c2
} }


struct StoryBrain{
var storyNumber = 0
let stories = [
Story(t: "You see a fork in the road", c1: "Take a left", c2: "Take a right"),
Story(t: "You see a tiger", c1: "Shout for help", c2: "Play dead"),
Story(t: "You find a treasure chest", c1: "Open it", c2: "Check for traps")
    
]

func getStory() -> String{
    return stories[storyNumber].storyTitle
}

mutating func nextStory(userChoice: String) {
    if storyNumber + 1 < stories.count{
        storyNumber += 1
    } else {
        storyNumber = 0
    }
}



}
```

func updateUI(){
storyLabel.text = StoryBrain.getStory()}

Answer (score 1):

I guess your doing Angelas "iOS & Swift - The Complete iOS App Development Bootcamp" course on Udemy.

Inside the ViewController, create a var:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var storyBrain = StoryBrain()
@IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel! }
```

This allows you to tap into your StoryBrain Model. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
StoryBrain.getStory()
          ^ Instance member 'getStory' cannot be used on type 'StoryBrain'
```

As the error indicates, `getStory` is an instance method, meaning that you can only call it on *instances* of `StoryBrain`. Here are a couple other suggestions:

```
struct StoryBrain {

    // Make private by default
    private let stories = [...]
    private var storyNumber = 0

    // Make a computed property
    var currentStoryTitle: String {
        stories[storyNumber].storyTitle
    }

    // Make the name imperative; reflects that this is a mutating function
    // Also don't need mutating anymore since this is a class
    func advanceStory(...) {
        ...
    }

}
```

If you initialize this object, like `let brain = StoryBrain()`, then you can use instance members like `advanceStory` and `currentStoryTitle` on `brain`. You’ll want to create this object/store it in whatever class you have `updateUI` in. If you use the same brain from a couple different places, then you might want to use the singleton pattern, which you can see in the original edit to this answer.

Comment: Couple things I wanted to add here. I wouldn't use a singleton unless you absolutely have to. Singletons are useful when you need a single instance throughout the entire app's lifecycle, but they can introduce global state which is hard to manage and can lead to bugs. So if you don't need a singleton, just create an instance instead. Also, one more suggestion. When you create a singleton you need a private initializer, otherwise callers can still create a normal instance! It's best to add a private init() {} to solve this.

Comment: @JKoko good points. Although a private initializer is common, many of the classes with singletons in the Swift API do not have private initializers. Given the “Brain” in the name, I figured this was the core of a global app state. If not, I agree with you that a simple instance is better.

Comment: I updated the answer to use an instance. The op can look in the edit history if they find that they use this object as a universal source of truth in their app.